# Showing day view of event on event click within an month or year view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, fullcalendar

I am new to using full calendar and was wondering if it is possible to show the day view (specifically the date of) the event which has been clicked on. This would need to take place if the event is clicked in the Year or month view.

Another thing that I would also like to know if possible can a lightbox (div that is shown above everything else) be shown when an event is clicked in the day view.

I have put in 2 days research in to these problems and although i have found -

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
},
```

I have not been able to adapt or change this to work correctly with the event.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you in-advance,
Chris

Comment: It is possible but your description must include more code of what you are trying to do. Pease use [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net) to do it.

Comment: Hello fabricio, i have added my code to http://fiddle.jshell.net/LZ65w/ although it shows no output. as it required an external json/php file. I found information for this very hard to research for event clicks.

Comment: JS Fiddle also takes external resources... :-) Look at [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LZ65w/1/). I'll take a look now.

Comment: thank you for the quick response, i have updated the current with default events so they are usable within the example http://fiddle.jshell.net/LZ65w/2/. I have worked out that i need to use '       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);' within an eventClick function. but I'm not 100% sure how to get the date field from the eventClick header.

Comment: Whilst looking through the code and trying work this out i found that '      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', calEvent.start);
    },      ' will work but will not change the view. Not sure if I am missing something or am trying an invalid attempt. http://fiddle.jshell.net/LZ65w/4/

Comment: The console reports an error in the plugin when you hoover over the event and changing the handler of the event to include an alert doesn't make the alert pop... Maybe the plugin is messed up or buggy.

Comment: Ok. The error reported on event mouse over was due to the fact that jQueryUI was not being included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
// Added Coded whilst trying to fix onEventClick       
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    jsEvent.preventDefault();

    // Go to and show day view for start date of clicked event
    calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', calEvent.start);
    calendar.fullCalendar('changeView', "basicDay");

    // Popup with information of clicked event
    if(calEvent.url) {
        $("#eventDisplay").html("<p><b>Title:</b> <a target='_blank' href='" + calEvent.url + "'>" + calEvent.title + "</a></p>");
    } else {
        $("#eventDisplay").html("<p><b>Title:</b> " + calEvent.title + "</p>");
    }
    $("#eventDisplay").append("<p><b>Start:</b> " + calEvent.start + "</p>");
    $("#eventDisplay").dialog({
        width: 400,
        modal: true
    });
},
// End Code onEventClick
```

**[Fidle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hJX8K/1/)** to show both requests: show a day view and popup jQuery UI dialog with event information in it.

Note that for events that fire external URLs, you should first .preventDefault. You may of course offer the link in the popup HTML to have the user click it if he really wants to do so. See example for Februray 28th event.

Comment: Thank you so much, this meets what I wanted to do and can be adapted to solve most of the issues that I am having.

Comment: Hello Fabricio, I have tried to move this into my project and the dialog popup that is working in fiddle is not showing. If i drop the display:none; from the css it shows (completely out of place) but it shows. Not sure where it is calling the state change, looking at the '        #eventDisplay' tags I cannot find a  '        #eventDisplay.show' any where and not sure how its working. I would like to learn this further and fix this issue.

Comment: Are you including [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/)? It is necessary for the FullCalendar to work properly and also gives you the popup dialog I used. As I mentioned in an earlier comment jQueryUI was not in your initial post and I have added it myself. Check the external resources in the fiddle because it is listed there.

Comment: Ah Ok, i see whats happening, i do have a version of jQueryUI installed with the calendar plugin but its a min version of the UI and doesnt contain the required features.

Comment: Ok, all sorted. Can't believe that it was something so simple that was causing so so many issues. Thank-you so much Fabricio.